# Developing mobile app with SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, mobile, nintex

I want to develop a mobile app (Android/iOS) using SharePoint online/365. There are workflows running made in Nintex and I want to show approval screens on mobile. Don't want to use Nintex mobile or SharePoint mobile feature and want to develop app.

I want to know what are some technical challenges that will be faced in it. As far as I understand, reading data from list can be done using REST APIs but how will I do authentication?

Will using ADFS with Azure solve authentication problem?

Thanks